# Same class in project and maven dependency

Tags: java, maven

I have 2 projects, lets say project A and project B. Project A has a Maven dependency on Project B. Both projects contain the class `Test` in the same package.

Now when I import,

```
import com.my.package.Test;
```

From another class in Project A, I think (at runtime) it uses the Test class from project B rather than the class contained in the same project.

Does anyone know if this is how it is supposed to work?

Comment: I think the classloader decides which to load. You can't control it.

Comment: That's exactly why we add a unique prefix to the packages (like `com.company.`). So this problem could only happen with packages in your own projects. Here you have to avoid this circumstance.

Comment: Okay I just wondered if there was a way to resolve the dependency from within the same project before the Maven dependency. I guess not :)I should just rename the package

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not supposed to have classes with the same FQN-s (fully qualified names, for example `com.foo.MyTest`). Having duplicate classes will only lead to these sort of problems. Remove the class from one of the two artifacts. Then use the `maven-jar-plugin` [to create a test-jar artifact](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/test-jar-mojo.html) so you can share you class between the two projects.

You can also have a look at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6469128/how-do-i-install-a-test-jar-in-maven/6469256#6469256).

Answer (score 0):

first classloader wins. Classloader order in maven is the same as dependency order, 
but you shall nbot have classes with same FQN in separate projects.