# maven dependency for multi-module project

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I have a strange issue with maven.

I'm running a dropwizard project that has multiple modules.

Project
 -> ServiceModule1
 -> ServiceModule2
 -> ModelsModule
 -> TestModule

All modules depend on the test module, and all of the service modules depend on the models module.

I'm using a test-jar to distribute the test module since all of the fixtures live in there.

So when I package my project, I do this:

```
cd testModule
mvn jar:test-jar
cd ..
mvn package
```

This works fine, except it means every time I want to package my project I have to run all the tests.  If I switch to

```
mvn package -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

I get a failure because my modules start to look for their dependency jars in maven central.

This is really frustrating, since the tests depend in a database and I don't want to install a database on every web server.

What should the "correct" setup be?

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6469128/how-do-i-install-a-test-jar-in-maven

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, if your ServiceModule1 wants to depend on ModelsModule, you can build it in two steps,

```
$ cd ModelsModule
$ mvn clean install
$ cd ..
$ cd ServiceModule1
$ mvn clean package
```

Please note `install` in step2,

In other words, it is not mandatory that all your lib should be in maven central. But it is mandatory that all of them should be in your local repo. `install` is a goal which can install a lib to your local repo.

Now this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6469128/how-do-i-install-a-test-jar-in-maven) will show you how to install a test jar to your local repo.